# Identifying the components of an electric motor

Tags: motor, induction-motor, electric-machine

[image]

I need to calculate the magnetic field in the airgap of this electrical motor (also other things such as torque) but I'm having difficulty identifying its components (airgap, rotor and its nucleus, direction of current in coil 1 and 2).
Also, how is the current induced in the rotor assuming the magnetic field produced by the external coils is parallel to the rotor coil?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The rotor is the round part. The air gap is the separation between the rotor and stator (2 rectangular parts). "Nucleus" is not a word that is customarily used to describe any part of an electric machine. If this is an induction machine, the coils cary alternating current. Any designation of current direction would be arbitrarily assigned to relate the instantaneous current in one coil as related to another. In an induction motor, current is induced in the rotor as a result of the rotating magnetic field of the stator. The lines drawn across the stator do not accurately describe the conductors

Comment: It looks more like a DC motor with the coil brushes omitted. It also fails to show the (steel) magnetic circuit between the outside edges two poles which would be required to minimise the magnetic losses which would be huge if made as shown.

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/686680/2451

Comment: Well, as drawn, you have two DC sources perfectly opposing each other.  If that's indeed the case, then the magnetic field in the area of the rotor is "zero", there is no induced current and the rotor doesn't turn.  This is because DC current's don't induce any magnetic fields at all.. you need AC to do that.  It wouldn't surprise me if this, indeed, is the 'correct answer' as sometimes these trick questions find their way into homework, teachers trying to get  you to think...  If that is NOT the case, I don't see how you could answer because there's no dimensions given.